# Intel C++ Compiler understanding what optimization is performed

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, intel

I have a code segment which is as simple as :

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if( data[i] > c && data[i] < r )
  {
    --data[i];
  }
}
```

It's a part of a large function and project. This is actually a rewrite of a different loop, which proved to be time consuming (long loops), but I was surprised by two things :

When data[i] was temporary stored like this :

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  const int tmp = data[i];
  if( tmp > c && tmp < r )
  {
    --data[i];
  }
}
```

It became more much slower. I don't claim this should be faster, but I can not understand why it should be so much slower, the compiler should be able to figure out if tmp should be used or not.

But more importantly when I moved the code segment into a separate function it became around four times slower. I wanted to understand what was going on, so I looked in the opt-report and in both cases the loop is vectorized and seem to do the same optimization.

So my question is what can make such a difference on a function which is not called a million times, but is time consuming in itself ? What to look for in the opt-report ?

I could avoid it by just keeping it inlined, but the why is bugging me.

UPDATE :

I should underline that my main concern is to understand, why it became slower, when moved to a separate function. The code example given with tmp variable, was just a strange example I encountered during the process.

Comment: Just the obligatory question: you have optimizations max on all builds?

Comment: Try taking a look at the generated assembly.

Comment: Yes all is compiled with O3. I have not looked at the assembly yet, simply because as said it's apart of a large project (also because I am no assembly expert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably register starved, and the compiler is having to load and store. I'm pretty sure that the native x86 assembly instructions can take memory addresses to operate on- i.e., the compiler can keep those registers free. But by making it local, you *may* changing the behaviour wrt. aliasing and the compiler may not be able to prove that the faster version has the same semantics, especially if there is some form of multiple threads in here, allowing it to change the code.

The function was slower when in a new segment likely because function calls not only can break the pipeline, but also create poor instruction cache performance (there's extra code for parameter push/pop/etc).

Lesson: Let the compiler do the optimizing, it's smarter than you. I don't mean that as an insult, it's smarter than me too. But really, especially the Intel compiler, those guys know what they're doing when targetting their own platform.

Edit: More importantly, you need to recognize that compilers are targetted at optimizing unoptimized code. They're not targetted at recognizing half-optimized code. Specifically, the compiler will have a set of triggers for each optimization, and if you happen to write your code in such a way as that they're not hit, you can avoid optimizations being performed *even if* the code is semantically identical.

And you also need to consider implementation cost. Not every function ideal for inlining can be inlined- just because inlining that logic is too complex for the compiler to handle. I know that VC++ will rarely inline with loops, even if the inlining yields benefit. You may be seeing this in the Intel compiler- that the compiler writers simply decided that it wasn't worth the time to implement.

I encountered this when dealing with loops in VC++- the compiler would produce different assembly for two loops in slightly different formats, even though they both achieved the same result. Of course, their Standard library used the ideal format. You *may* observe a speedup by using `std::for_each` and a function object.

Comment: I agree on the lesson, but I didn't want to be smarter than the compiler, just to understand and learn to improve the code to fit better to the compiler. The actual problem is to under stand why it became slower when moved to another file.

Comment: @Bo Jensen: That's because many compilers cannot perform inlining across translation units due to the way C++ is designed. I believe that recent versions of VC++ can do this and possibly GCC too, but I don't think that Intel can.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the the function is in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the compiler should be able to identify that as unused code and remove it/not compile it. That doesn't mean it actually does identify it and remove it.

Your best bet is to look at the generated assembly and check to see exactly what is going on. Remember, just because a clever compiler could be able to figure out how to do an optimization, it doesn't mean it can.

If you do check, and see that the code is not removed, you might want to report that to the intel compiler team. It sounds like they might have a bug.